# Optimization: Stochastic Gradient Descent with batch sizes 1 and 2

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning

I have googled a lot about how GD, SGD, Batch GD and Mini-batch GD work and why they differ. However, when it comes to writing a code all those explanations couldn't help!

I need to solve below question:

### For a random A and b (20 by 4 and 20 by 1), try stochastic gradient descent with mini-batch sizes $B=1$ and $B=2$. compare the convergence rates_ the ratio $r_k=‖x_{(k+1)}-x^* ‖/‖x_{k}-x^* ‖$.

Based on what I have understood about SGD, I have written:

```
clear all
clc
N = 20;
D = 4;
A = rand(N, D);
b = rand(N, 1);

n = size(A, 1);
showiterinfo = true;
x = rand(1, size(A, 2)); %initial guess
alpha = 0.005;
maxiter = 1000;
tol = 1e-4;

 for i = 1 : maxiter
        for j = 1:size(A, 1)
            % Derivative(Finding the residual)
            r = (A(j, :)'*(A(j, :) * x' - b(j)));
            % Updating x
            x = x - alpha * r';
        end

        % Find residual and Mean-Squared Error with Data Set

        residual = (1/n)*(A'*(A * x' - b));
        overall_mse = (1/(2*n)) * sum((A * x' - b).^2);

        % Display iteration info
        if showiterinfo
            disp(['Iteration ' num2str(i) ' : Mean-squared error = ' num2str(overall_mse)]);
        end

        % Check for convergence
        if norm(residual) <= tol
            fprintf('\nChange in x less than specified tolerance\n')
        break
        end
    end
```

However, I am not sure whether it is correct or not!
Is my test correct ? (according to the problem statement above). Should I generate A and b like this for this problem?
Is it SGD or Batch GD ?!?
How can I adjust batch size !!!

Anyone has any idea ?!

All ideas / helps are highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a training data set $\{(x_i, y_i):i=1, \dots n\}$ and a loss function $L$, the update rule for the GD is

$$
w_{t+1} \gets w_t + \alpha\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\nabla L(f_{w_t}(x_i), y_i) 
$$

in other words, we update the parameters based on the gradient over all points in the training data.

The update for the SGD is

$$
w_{t+1} \gets w_t + \alpha\nabla L(f_{w_t}(x_i), y_i)
$$

i.e, the update is based on the gradient over a single data point chosen with probability equal to $\frac{1}{n}$.

Finally, the mini batch GD is given by

$$
w_{t+1} \gets w_t + \alpha\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k\nabla L(f_{w_t}(x_i), y_i) 
$$
where $k$ is the batch size, and the $k$ samples are also chosen accordingly to a uniform distribution without repetition.

Once you know the difference between the algorithms, the batch size can be chosen via grid or random search, typical values are 16, 32, 64, 128.